# What is the number of bit-strings (that is, strings consisting of 0's and 1's) of length 8 where the number of 0's is equal to the number of 1's?

Tags: combinatorics

What is the number of bit-strings (that is, strings consisting of 0's and 1's) of length 8 where the number of 0's is equal to the number of 1's?

For example, there are two such strings of length two: 01 and 10.

TIA.

Comment: $$ \binom{8}{4}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a bit string of length 8 you have 8 'places' to place a 0 or 1. When you have an equal number of 0's and 1's, you have 4 0's and 4 1's. When you have chosen were to place the 0's in the bit string the indices of the 1's are automatically determined. You have $\binom{8}{4}$ possibilities to place the 0's, and therefore $\binom{8}{4}$ possible strings with equal number of 0's and 1's.